# Entity Framework 6 Update from Database ignores deleted columns, type changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Am I missing something here?

I've a .net 4.5.1 project with an Entity Framework model created from a SQL 2005 database (Connection type is SQL Server also), via "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

This works fine. That is, until I update the database. If I add new tables or columns to existing tables all is well, but if I delete a column, the update just doesn't work properly. it also throws out errors when I alter the column type.

This same problem was reported a long time ago: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update.html#.UytNrvldVD0, but it seems so ridiculous I can't believe I am not missing something. Surely I'm doing something wrong? How can I get the model to update properly?

Comment: What if you remove the table and readd it?

Comment: I expect that will work, but I've just been doing the update over the last couple of weeks, saving, and then VS spits back errors, so then I know which fields to manually delete from the model.

The update process is able to change field size (e.g. varchar(20) -> varchar(50)).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I opened up the Model, removed the changed tables from the diagram, then Updated from the Database and re-added the tables. 
EF brought the table back in again with the correct structure.  Save The model, Rebuild the project, everything turns up as expected.

I am not sure why it doesn't detect the deleted columns.  I believe there's also issues if you change the data type of the columns, but I've not tested it.  But the above solution has worked for me so far.